# CSS: Unable to establish page break

Tags: css

I have encountered a fair amount of roadblocks in trying to establish a page break on every 3rd `item_wrapper`. My element structure and general styles are as such:

```
<div class='main_wrapper'>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='main_details'>
      <div class='main_items_container'>
        <div class='main_items_wrapper'>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
          <div class='item_wrapper'>...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.main_wrapper {
  display: inline-block
}

.main {
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
}

.main_items_wrapper {
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
}

.item_wrapper {
  display: block
}
```

The following is my initial solution:

```
@media print {
  .main_items_wrapper:nth-child(3n) {
    break-after: always
  }
}
```

Please note that I have attempted to follow the recommendations of many posts - display, width, height, float, etc. Unfortunately, I just cannot get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `item_wrapper:nth-child(3)`?

Comment: your html is wrong. you have not close the single quote of main_items_wrapper class and item_wrapper class. Print css use .main_items_wrapper .item_wrapper:nth-child(3n)

Comment: how are you testing whether the page-break is in effect? with print dialogue or are you actually printing?

Comment: Unfortunately, `.main_items_wrapper .item_wrapper:nth-child(3n)` does not work. I have previously tried that with no success. As for printing, I have done so and it is a reflection of what is seen in the dialogue. This certainly is a weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a horizontal line across the webpage as a page break, then you can use the hr tag. You can set the height and width to your specifications.

For some reason I can show the hr tag because it is producing a line here. Below is an example (gray line)

---

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears as though the flexbox associated with `.main_items_wrapper` was the problem. Certainly a lesson learned. Thank you to those that took the time to assist me.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27067859)

Comment: @dan1st: This isn't thanking anyone for an answer, but rather answering their own question. Neither the other answer nor the comments isolate the flexbox. The thank you was just an acknowledgement of the effort provided by other contributors.

Comment: That said, this would be a more useful answer with additional details as to _why_ the flexbox was introducing this behavior—as well as any additional details you needed to implement to fix this.